# Получить массив реквестов в Node.js или в Express

Tags: node.js, express

Есть ли в Express или в самом Node.js возможность получить массив обрабатываемых в данный момент реквестов?

Я хочу при ошибке отслеживать их количество и когда останется только один - закрыть его со статусом 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сомневаюсь, что есть штатная возможность получить все обрабатывающиеся в данный момент запросы.

Реализация такой коллекции очень проста и на чистом node.js выглядит примерно так:

```
const http = require('http');
const clients = [];

http.createServer((req, res) => {

    clients.push(res);
    res.on('close', () => clients.splice(clients.indexOf(res), 1));

    ...
    res.end('ok');

}).listen(3000);
```